# Save custom struct in Flat file

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Following is the custom structure. I wanted to store the array of custom structures that is [details]. Am not able to store [details] in file. While writing this [details in file, application is crashing 'invalid json format'

```
struct details : Identifiable {
    let id  = UUID()
    var name : String?
    var time : String?
    var msg : [MsgDetails]?
    var loc : String?
    var type : String?
}
```

Write in the file : msgArray is array of details. msgArray = [details].

```
extension Array {
    var jsonStringRepresentation: String? {
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [])
        guard jsonData != nil else {return nil}
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
        guard jsonString != nil else {return nil}
        return jsonString! as String

    }
}
```

In the below code NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData is returning nil

```
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(self.fileName)
            let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: msgArray.jsonStringRepresentation!, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            do {
                try data!.write(to: fileURL)
            } catch let error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: please show us your code you tried so far. this is not a "we write code for you for free" platform, but a "we help you with your existing code" platform.

Comment: @Chris, updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Codable` instead of `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert models to data and write to file. Assuming that your model contains only basic types, all you have to do is conform to `Codable` protocol.

```
struct Details : Identifiable, Codable {
    ...
}
```

Write to file:

```
extension Array where Element: Encodable {

    func saveToFile(fileName: String) throws {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
            if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
                let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
            } else {
                //throw some error
            }
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }

}
```

Saved file can be read like this:

```
func readFile(fileName: String) throws {
    do {
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Details].self, from: data)
            print("decoded: ", decoded)
        } else {
            //throw some error
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }

}
```

If you can replace the `UIImage` in your model with its `Data`, `Codable` conformance can be achieved automatically. Get the imageData from `UIImage` using `image.pngData()`.

```
struct MsgDetails: Codable {
    var imageData: Data?
    var text: String?
    var date: Date?

    var image: UIImage? {
        if let data = imageData {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: When i implement Codable in struct like  struct details : Identifiable, Codable {
    let id  = UUID()
    var name : String?
    var time : String?
    var msg : [MsgDetails]?
    var loc : String?
    var type : String?
}  Am getting error like Type 'details' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' Type 'details' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Comment: What are the contents of MsgDetails?

Comment: If you want to use NSKeyedArchiver, your model must be a class inheriting from NSObject and adopt the NSCoding protocol and it's required methods. Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816174/5443937

Comment: MsgDetails is the objects of the msg class.        class msg {
    // 2.Properties
    var text: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var date: NSDate?
}

Comment: UIImage doesn't conform to Codable. That's why you are getting that error.